# Will code built with IDTSComponentMetaData100 work against SQL Server 2016

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2016

We have an application that generates SSIS packages for SQL Server based on user input and file scanning. The code that builds the packages is based on the methods in the [IDTSComponentMetaData100 Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.pipeline.wrapper.idtscomponentmetadata100.aspx).

Browsing that documentation, I note that the available "versions" only cover SQL Server 2012 and 2014. Does this mean that SQL Server 2016 will not be back compatible with this interface?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so based on this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.pipeline.wrapper.idtscomponentmetadata130.aspx